# Recorrer un DataGridView en C#

Tags: c#

Necesito pasar todos los datos de un `DataGridView` a una base de datos en MySQL, la única opción de hacer es recorriendo el `DataGrid` e insertando.

Mi código anterior era:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRenglon in dtaPagos.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dgvRenglon.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(dgvRenglon.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(dgvRenglon.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
}
```

Pero no me funciona para lo que quiero o está mal planteado.

¿Cómo puedo recorrer fila del `DataGrid` y sacar los datos de cada una de ellas?

> Mi DataGrid

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Solucion

```
for (int fila = 0; fila < dtaPagos.Rows.Count-1; fila++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < dtaPagos.Rows[fila].Cells.Count; col++)
                {
                    string valor = dtaPagos.Rows[fila].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(valor);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Manuel, por favor lee: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes recorer tu `DataGridView` de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtaPagos.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(row.Cells["Pago"].Value.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(row.Cells["Cantidad"].Value.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(row.Cells["Observaciones"].Value.ToString());
}
```

## Actualización

Se edita ejemplo de código con el nombre de las columnas.

Comment: **me marca error** `Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto`

Comment: @ManuelMorales debes cambiar `"NombreColumna1"` por el nombre de la(s) columna(s) que tengas en tu `DataGridView`

Comment: si lo hice, `MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());`

Comment: ¿Cuántas columnas tienes en tu `DataGridView` y cómo se llaman?

Comment: si me muestra el dato pero luego me manda ese error. ya agrefue la imagen del datagrid.

Comment: Edite el ejemplo de código con el nombre de las columnas, espero que así sea el `Id` que les pusiste en código

Comment: **Error** `No se pudo encontrar la columna denominada Pago. Nombre del parametro: columnName`

Comment: ya pude solucionarlo, puedes checar la actualización de como quedo.