# ¿Como obtener valores de un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework

estoy renderizando valores de una tabla de sql en un datagridview y necesito tomar los datos de cada celda en cada row cuando le clic a la row , estuve tratado de hacer esto, pero devuelve vació.

Aquí lleno la tabla

```
 using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {
            db.AspNetUsers.Load();


            dataGridViewPF.DataSource = 
                db.AspNetUsers.Select
                (x => new { Id = x.Id, Email = x.Email, UserName = x.UserName }).ToList();
        }
```

y aquí es donde quiero cachar lo valores, ahorita solo estoy tratando de tomar el de una celda, pero necesito de toda la row y aún así no me esta tirando nada

```
private void DataGridViewPF_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewPF.SelectedRows)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("yeah"+ row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

me devulve

> "yeah      "

Comment: Usa un bucle anidado, un for que recorra las filas y el for anidado que recorra las columnas. Para más información: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48527/recorrer-un-datagridview-en-c

Comment: mas o menos, ahí recorro todas las celdas de todas las columas y yo solo quiero los datos la row en donde di el click

Answer (score 1):

> > necesito tomar los datos de cada celda en cada row cuando le clic a la row , estuve tratado de hacer esto, pero devuelve vació.

Necesitarías hacer uso de las propiedades (en este caso de [RowIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.rowindex?view=netframework-4.8)) de la clase [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.columnindex?view=netframework-4.8).

El algoritmo sería:

- Obtienes la cantidad total de columnas del GridView (eso lo haces con la propiedad [ColumnCount](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columncount?view=netframework-4.8)).
- Obtienes el índice de fila de la celda que se le dio click.
- Detectas si el índice no es -1. Esto es necesario para evitar un posible desbordamiento de búfer, porqué el evento [CellContentClick](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick?view=netframework-4.8) se invoca también cuando le das click en el encabezado de una columna y en ese caso, [RowIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.rowindex?view=netframework-4.8) valdrá -1.
- Ejecutas un bucle for para recorrer cada columna de la respectiva fila (obtenida de [RowIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.rowindex?view=netframework-4.8)).

El código en C# sería:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int totalColumnas = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
            int indiceFila = e.RowIndex;
            if(indiceFila == -1) return;
            for(int i = 0; i != totalColumnas; ++i)
                MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[indiceFila].Cells[i].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```